# holding values between Windows forms

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I am having a problem about holding values while scrolling between forms. I have two Windows forms. One of them is Main and the other one is NewUser

While I'm in Main and click to **Change User** button:

```
NewUser yk = new NewUser();
        yk.ShowDialog();
```

When NewUser form loads:

```
private void NewUser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (impersonatedUser == null) 
        {
            txtNewUserName.Select();
            return;
        }


        btnRevert.Enabled = true; //user may revert back to the old user
        btnLogon.Enabled = false;
        txtNewUserName.Enabled = false;
        txtPassword.Enabled = false;
        btnRevert.Select();            
    }
```

reverting:

```
private void btnRevert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // revert to previous user
        impersonatedUser.Undo();
        btnRevert.Enabled = false;
        btnLogon.Enabled = true;            
    }
```

after I impersonated the user I can revert back to the user but if I close the form and then click Change User button in Main to revert user, I expect in this session already impersonated so impersonatedUser is not null and btnRevert.enabled = true; but everything starts as creating a new form. Therefore I can't revert  If I don't want to lose variables in NewForm what should I do? Should I use **this.Visible = false** instead of **this.Close()** etc.? By the way I am not having any problem in Impersonation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in Main form

```
NewUser yk = newUser()
yk.ShowDialog()
```

will always create a new object of `NewUser` form. So if your object `impersonatedUser`declared in class `NewUser` it will be initialized as new again.

If, I guess,  for you enough to keep in memory information of object `impersonatedUser`, then you can create a object of `impersonatedUser` in `Main` form and just pass it to `NewUser` form.

in your `Main` form:

```
Private YourClassOfUser impersonatedUser;
```

in you `NewUser` form :

```
Private YourClassOfUser impersonatedUser;
//Then create a custom constructor with parameter
Public void NewUser(YourClassOfUser inImpersonatedUser)
{
    this.impersonatedUser = inImpersonatedUser;
}
```

and then in `Main` form open a `NewUser`form with this constructor

```
NewUser yk = newUser(this.impersonatedUser);
yk.ShowDialog();
```

If you can to show some code about how you initialized `impersonatedUser` object in `NewUser` form the answer can be little bid another